# JavaScript: group objects of array per attribute in one object with a list

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently working on a project in which I have an array of objects, each with "attribute" and "variation".

I need to group them as one object per attribute having the "attribute" and a list of "variations".

**Sample Input:**

```
[
    {
        "attribute": "Pack",
        "variation": "full"
    },
    {
        "attribute": "Size",
        "variation": "M"
    },
    {
        "attribute": "Color",
        "variation": "blue"
    },
    {
        "attribute": "Size",
        "variation": "X"
    },
    {
        "attribute": "Color",
        "variation": "red"
    },
    {
        "attribute": "Pack",
        "variation": "half"
    }
]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[
    {
        "attribute": "Pack",
        "variations": ["full", "half" ]
    },
    {
        "attribute": "Size",
        "variations": ["M", "X"]
    },
    {
        "attribute": "Color",
        "variations": ["blue", "red"]
    },
]
```

Comment: could you include what have you tried

Comment: There's no [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) in your question -> [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: @MajedBadawi Why did you reopen the question? How is this not a duplicate [How can I group an array of objects by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-can-i-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)? o.O

Comment: You even changed the title into what the the dupe target does!

Comment: How would OP benefit from that? It's a different target schema. Not every grouping question should be marked as duplicate... If there's another duplicate please suggest.

Comment: So there's not even an attempt to solve this on their own... But there's a dupe target that would only need an additional `Object.entries()` or some minor adjustments... And yet OP gets a free solution (which also has dupe targets...). Got it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over the array while updating an object accumulator where the attribute is the `key` and the corresponding object (attribute and variations) is the `value`. In every iteration, in order to update the variations, you need to check if there's already an existing record for the current attribute in `acc` with a `variations` list (you can use [`optional-chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)) and set a default value of an empty array (you can use [`nullish-coalescing-operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator))
- Using [`Object#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), return the list of grouped objects, each with attribute and variations

```js
const arr = [ { "attribute": "Pack", "variation": "full" }, { "attribute": "Size", "variation": "M" }, { "attribute": "Color", "variation": "blue" }, { "attribute": "Size", "variation": "X" }, { "attribute": "Color", "variation": "red" }, { "attribute": "Pack", "variation": "half" } ];

const res = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((acc, { attribute, variation }) => ({
    ...acc,
    [attribute]: { 
      attribute, 
      variations: [...(acc[attribute]?.variations ?? []), variation] 
    }
  }), {})
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Throwing a bunch of code on OP without any explanation on how it works (you're using quite some new stuff in there) doesn't really teach/help OP or future readers. Also why the answer at all if there's a perfect duplicate for this really common type of question?

Comment: @Andreas I added some explanations. I don't think the duplicate is quite exactly what OP is trying to achieve, it's not grouping the objects, but the variations of every attribute...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
let inputObjs = [
    {
        "attribute": "Pack",
        "variation": "full"
    },
    {
        "attribute": "Size",
        "variation": "M"
    },
    {
        "attribute": "Color",
        "variation": "blue"
    },
    {
        "attribute": "Size",
        "variation": "X"
    },
    {
        "attribute": "Color",
        "variation": "red"
    },
    {
        "attribute": "Pack",
        "variation": "half"
    }
];

let grouped = [];
let attributeIndex = {};
let groupedIndex = 0;
for(k = 0; k < inputObjs.length;k++){
    const obj = inputObjs[k];
  const attrKey = `_${obj.attribute}`;
  if(typeof attributeIndex[attrKey] != 'undefined'){
    //console.log(grouped[attributeIndex[attrKey]].variations,grouped[attributeIndex[attrKey]].variations.indexOf(obj.variation),obj.variation);
    if(grouped[attributeIndex[attrKey]].variations.indexOf(obj.variation) == -1){
          grouped[attributeIndex[attrKey]].variations.push(obj.variation);
        }
  }else{
    attributeIndex[attrKey] = groupedIndex;
    grouped[attributeIndex[attrKey]] = {attribute:obj.attribute,variations:[]};
    grouped[attributeIndex[attrKey]].variations.push(obj.variation);
    groupedIndex += 1;
  }
  //console.log(obj);
}
console.log(grouped);
//console.log(attributeIndex);
```